# Blood On The Clocktower - Mayor / Travelers

Tags: blood-on-the-clocktower

Trouble Brewing Almanac:
Travelers count toward the three living players for a Mayor win.
So why do living Travelers need to be exiled before the final day with a living Mayor? This is what the almanac says, but I don't know why. I don't understand the difference between 3 normal characters and 2 normal / 1 traveler, on the final day. Yes, the Traveler means that the demon is one of the other two, changing the odds to 50% for the good players to win by execution, but the Mayor win seems to be unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Good can't win in that scenario, because Evil has already won.  With only two non-Traveler players alive, Evil wins because Travelers (who cannot be the Demon) don't count against Evil's win condition, per the rulebook:

> Travelers do not count toward the evil team winning when
> just two players remain alive. For example, if five players
> are still alive, but three of them are Travelers, then evil wins.

So if Good wants to attempt a Mayor win, they'll need to exile the living Travelers at "final three" before refusing to execute.

Comment: That excerpt makes it clear, thanks. I may have downloaded an earlier version of the almanac. I'm waiting for my copy of BOTC to be shipped to the retailer.

Comment: @Bafs that excerpt is from the main rulebook, not the script-specific almanac :) hope you enjoy the game when it arrives.